# Как выполнять бесконечный цикл, чтобы он не блокировал работу бота?

Tags: python, python-3.x, aiogram, asyncio

После инициализации бота, бот перестаёт отвечать на команды.
В цикле запущена задача для проверки сайта на изменения.

после того как цикл становится на паузу 5 сек, после этого бот начинает реагировать.

Как сделать так чтобы бот всё время реагировал на команды и в фоне выполнялись нужные действия?

Пример кода:

```
import asyncio
import urllib3
urllib3.disable_warnings()
import requests
import config
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher, executor, types

# инициализируем бота
#bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN, proxy=config.PROXY_URL, proxy_auth=config.PROXY_AUTH)
bot = Bot(token=config.API_TOKEN)
# For example use simple MemoryStorage for Dispatcher.
dp = Dispatcher(bot)

# Команда активации меню
@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start_bot(message: types.Message):
    await message.answer("Работаем")

headers = requests.utils.default_headers()
headers.update({
    'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/83.0.4103.106 Safari/537.36",
    'DNT': '1',
})
session_requests = requests.session()

async def task_back():
    while True:
        print("back task")
        for i in range(200):
            print("oblom %s " % (i))

            session_requests.get(
                "https://stopgame.ru/games/filter?p=%s" % (i),
                verify=False,
                headers = headers,
                timeout=10, allow_redirects=True,
            )
        
        await asyncio.sleep(5)

async def worker(name, queue):
    while True:
        # Получить "рабочий элемент" вне очереди.
        json_input = await queue.get()

        if(str(json_input["name"]) == "test"):
            await task_back()

        # Спать "sleep_for" секунд.
        await asyncio.sleep(1)

        # Сообщение очереди, для обработки «рабочего элемента».
        queue.task_done()

async def main(dp):
    # Установка команд бота
    await dp.bot.set_my_commands([
        types.BotCommand("start", "Запустить бота"),
    ])

    await dp.skip_updates()
    await dp.start_polling()

async def main2():
    resources = [
        {
            "name": "test"
        }
    ]

    """
    Запускаем программу
    """
    #while False:
    #while True:
    if(True):
        queue = asyncio.Queue()
        
        # Даем очереди нужные нам ссылки для скачивания
        for name in resources:
            queue.put_nowait(name)

        # Запускаем потом и очередь
        tasks = []
        for i in range(int(len(resources))):
            task = asyncio.create_task(worker(f'worker-{i}', queue))
            tasks.append(task)
    
        # Ждем завершения работы очереди
        await queue.join()

        # Отменить рабочие задания.
        for task in tasks:
            task.cancel()
        # Подождать, пока все рабочие задачи не будут отменены.
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks, return_exceptions=True)

        await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    asyncio.ensure_future(main(dp))
    asyncio.ensure_future(main2())
    loop.run_forever()
```

Comment: Используйте потоки

Comment: threading тебе в помощь

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом цикле requests замени на aiohttp или запусти в executor https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#executing-code-in-thread-or-process-pools

Второй цикл не блокирует